# Joining PageViews and Request in Application Insights Log Analytics

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I want to join pageViews that are coming from the AppInsights browser SDK, to the request on the backend. I don't see a foreign key that makes sense, is there one OOTB? or do I need to code something to join them together?

To add context, I am interested in pageView duration by cloudRoleInstance (server), but cloudRoleInstance is only available on requests.

I tried the following, and did not work, I supose the operation IDs are not the same.

```
pageViews
| join (requests) on operation_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join by Operation ID (operation_Id).

Here is the query which returns all documents for a particular operation_Id:

```
union *
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where operation_Id == "<operation_id>"
```

[image]

Comment: What's up with the XML? How about request and pageView?

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in exactly the same thing and this is how I ended up solving it:

1. Set a "cloud_RoleInstance" cookie for each response from the server so that the client javascript would know which role instance sent the last response.
2. Add a TelemetryInitializer to the client-side Application Insights instance which pulls the RoleInstance cookie and adds it as data to the telemetry collected client-side.

*The reason I did it this way instead of joining on operationId as the other answer says is because operationId seemed to span many requests on the server, sometimes over the course of a half an hour. Maybe that has is because of the way our Single Page Application is set up, but operationId just wasn't working for me.

---

### Code

*BaseController.cs::BeginExecute* (We have our own BaseController which all other controllers inherit from)

```
var roleInstanceCookie = requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Get("cloud_RoleInstance");
roleInstanceCookie.Value = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id;
requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(roleInstanceCookie);
```

---

*ApplicationInsights.js* (This contains our AI snippet that loads AI, currently using version 2.3.1 of the JS SDK)

```
// ... initialization snippet ...
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
    envelope.data.cloud_RoleInstance = getCookie("cloud_RoleInstance");
});
```

---

The cloud_RoleInstance will then end up in the customDimensions column of your PageViews in Application Insights

[image]